# How to add js and html5 <canvas> content inside of the slider?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas, slideshow

I'm looking to add some interactive components to a slideshow. In this particular implementation, I would like to add http://wagerfield.github.io/flat-surface-shader/.

I'm not sure if this is the right implementation or if a video would be a better bet. That being said, are there methods of bringing JavaScript heavy/HTML/CSS interactive components inside of a slider such as flexslider or Royal slider?

Comment: Am i posting in the right area?

Comment: Yes, just handle it as if it was an image